# За что дается "-5" в репутации

Tags: поддержка

Заглянул в "последние достижения" [image: введите сюда описание изображения] и увидел там -5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не принциально, но интересно, почему именно `-5`? За голос "против" обычно `-2`, если удаляется пользователь снимется вся оценка. Не понятно

[Сам ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1410147/209304)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Снятие галочки принятого ответа и плюс. По идее ты это у себя в профиле должен видеть.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: ясно-понятно) да, в профиле видно, если галочку раскрыть. Обычная арифметика